# how to verify a omniture tag fired correctly using tamper data

Tags: web-analytics, adobe-analytics

Sorry for asking a newbie question here. I've searched on the web but everyone else seems to know the answer so I can't find any definite words. I need to verify my omniture tag fires correctly in tamper data. Should I look for a call from adobetag.com? Or what other URL call should I look for?

Answer (score 6):

If your implementation is Omniture's 3rd party cookie, the request will be sent to `2o7.net` or `omtrdc.net` depending on the version of SiteCatalyst you are using (and whether or not it is through their TagManager). If it is a first party implementation, it will be to your own domain that you worked with Omniture ClientCare to setup.

You can certainly look for those domains in any number of addons or other programs (built-in net console, firebug, httpfox, charles proxy - basically anything that can see requests being made) but FYI there are a couple of options that make it easier to see Omniture requests.

If you are using FireFox and have the firebug addon, there is an extension to firebug called [omnibug](http://www.rosssimpson.com/dev/omnibug.html). It adds an extra tab to firebug that will show you requests to Omniture made, and even makes it an easy to read format (It also reports other ones like GA and WebTrends).

Alternatively, Omniture provides a debugging tool called [DigitalPulse](http://blogs.adobe.com/digitalmarketing/analytics/meet-the-new-digitalpulse-debugger/).  Basically you create a bookmark and for the location/url you put the javascript code snippet.  Then on the page you click the bookmark and it pops up a window showing info about any omniture requests made.

Answer (score 3):

Filter to requests containing **b/ss**

They are the requests being sent to Omniture SiteCatalyst.

See these references if you need more information -

http://blogs.adobe.com/digitalmarketing/analytics/validate-your-mobile-app-measurement-implementation/

http://blogs.adobe.com/digitalmarketing/analytics/custom-link-tracking-capturing-user-actions/

http://emptymind.org/validating-page-tags-with-httpfox/

http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/webanalytics/message/24232

Answer (score 1):

In short look for: "/b/ss" however this guy wrote a very in depth article on how to do that with HTTPFox it's a good read with screenshots: http://www.mikewebguy.com/2013/08/21/httpfox-helps-you-verify-what-data-is-being-sent-to-your-analytics-provider/